# Creating dynamic POJOs and set values to it

Tags: java, class, dynamic, pojo

```
final Map<String, Class<?>> properties = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
properties.put("jobName", String.class);
properties.put("companyName", String.class);
properties.put("totalApplicantForJob", String.class);        
final Class<?> beanClass = createBeanClass("ApplicantCountVsJobBoards", properties);

public static Class<?> createBeanClass (final String className, final Map<String, Class<?>> properties) {
    final BeanGenerator beanGenerator = new BeanGenerator();
    // NamingPolicy policy = 
    //beanGenerator.setNamingPolicy(null);
    BeanGenerator.addProperties(beanGenerator, properties);
    return (Class<?>) beanGenerator.createClass();
}
```

How will I add values to these class object.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You want to put the class returned by createBeanClass to the properties `HasMap`?

Comment: Are you using cglib's `BeanGenerator`?

Comment: After creating the class I need to create an instance of that class and set values to each variable of the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cglib's `BeanGenerator` not only generates a dynamic class, it also adds accessor methods. So how about doing a reflective method call like this:

```
Object instance = beanClass.newInstance(); // Creates a new object of your dynamic class
Method setJobName = beanClass.getMethod("setJobName", String.class); // Gets the setJobName method that takes one String argument
method.invoke(instance, "Super Cool Job");
```

Your bean is now (partially) populated.

There might be more efficient ways, probably, this is just to show you the concept.